# Enabling Parse Local Data Store and PFQueryTableViewController issues

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Once I updated the Parse SDK and enabled local data store, the PFQueryTableViewControllers within my app started getting stuck on "loading". If I disable local data store they will work again. Is there currently an issue using PFQueryTableViewController with local data store?

Comment: There are lots of issues going on with the release of this. Just review SO for other questions similar to this. It's simply a bug you can't do anything about until they release a fix

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but I already searched on this for quite a while and there was no documentation on this specific issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're using the cache policy but this may help, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27730344/892991)